# How to save an GRPC stream for reusement

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have an GRPC server which provides an function and returns a stream.
I want to save the stream onto a `map[string]grpc.Stream` - this works so far.

My problem is that the stream gets closed after the function that returns the stream finishes its logic.

This is, what I have so far:

```
func (s *server) CheckConnection(initMessage *LighterGRPC.InitMessage, stream LighterGRPC.Lighter_CheckConnectionServer) error {
    //Do something magic
    streams[initMessage.DeviceID] = stream

    error := stream.Send(&LighterGRPC.ColorMessage{DATA})
    if error {
        log.Println(error)
    }

    //Tried
    //for { }

    return error
}
```

I already tried to let the function never return anything with an `for {}` before the return (as commented in the code above), but that didn't helped and I don't think, that this could be the solution.

Is there a way to leave the stream open so I can send data later in runtime over it to the client?

Comment: Seems like a use case for channels and goroutines.

Comment: But then I wouldn't have the stream to send data back to the client or am I wrong?

Comment: I was more thinking something along the lines of run this method as a goroutine and use channels to keep it running until you send it some signal which indicates it's time to return.

Comment: That doesn't help, the stream gets closed even if i let run the function forever

Comment: Have you checked to see if the client is closing the stream? Whats the delay between interactions on the stream? Is the client encountering an error when reading from the stream (this will close the stream automatically) ? Preventing the return of the gRPC server function should keep the stream alive, as long as the client doesn't close the stream. If that function returns, the server will close the stream.

Answer (score 2):

For those of you, who may encounter the same problem, here is the quick solution. Basically, you need to wrap your stream in a struct, so that there is an error chan. Return will block until there is an error occuring when you execute stream.Send()

```
type Connection struct {
    stream LighterGRPC.Lighter_CheckConnectionServer
    error  chan error
}
```

You map will be like:

```
type Server struct {
    ....
    conns map[string]Connection
}
```

And your RPC for creating a stream at the end should be like:

```
conn := Connection{
    stream: stream,
    error:  make(chan error),
}
s.conns[initMessage.DeviceID] = conn

return <-conn.error
```

That way your stream will be stored in a map while being "active".